# For loop in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I stuck with for loop condition in Pipeline

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages{     
    stage ('Showing Working Space') {
        when {
            anyOf {
                environment name: 'Test', value: 'ALL'
                environment name: 'Test', value: 'IMAGE'
            }               
        }           
         steps {
             sh "echo Display ${Var1}"
             script{
         sh 'for service in (echo "$Var1"|sed "s/,/ /g");do echo $service; done'
            }
          }
         }
    }
    }
```

Getting error like " syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Var1 = has multiple values

Need to execute the "For loop" to pass the values to another script
Please help on this

Comment: `in (echo` -> `in $(echo`

Comment: what a miss...Thanks..it works

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Showing Working Space') {
            when {
                anyOf {
                    environment name: 'Test', value: 'ALL'
                    environment name: 'Test', value: 'IMAGE'
                }               
            }           
            steps {
                sh "echo Display ${Var1}"
                script {
                    sh 'for service in $(echo "$Var1"|sed "s/,/ /g"); do echo $service; done'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In essence, replace `service in (echo` with `service in $(echo` (note the `$`).